# Issues with the rss feed in internet explorer

Tags: php, laravel, internet-explorer, rss

favorite

Using the laravel framework and eclipse mars to write my code. I am having issues with my rss feed.  It was working before, but now whenever I try to run it, I get a Feed code error - Internet Explorer cannot display this feed - This feed contains code errors. What am I doing wrong?

app\Http\routes.php

```
<?php
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes       
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

/*Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});*/
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('product', 'WelcomeController@product');
//Route::controller('WelcomeController');

Route::get("home", function(){return view('welcome');});
Route::get("products", 'ProductController@products');
Route::get("product/{id}", 'ProductController@product');
//Route::get('product/{id}', function ($id) {
//  return $id;
//});
Route::get("orders", 'OrderController@orders');
Route::get("order/{id}", 'OrderController@order');
Route::get("rssfeed", 'RssFeedController@rssfeed');

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

app\Http\Controllers\RssFeedController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class RssFeedController extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function rssfeed(){
        return view('rssfeed');
    }
}
?>
```

resources\views\rssfeed.php

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
    $serverName = "CMSCRSST.db.11959136.hostedresource.com";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"CMSCRSST", "UID"=>"cmscrsst", "PWD"=>"RS#889st3");
    $rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
    $rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0">';
    $rssfeed .= '<channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>My RSS feed</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>http://localhost:8080/rsst/CloudRobotics/rsst/public/index</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>This is the RSS feed for CloudRobotics</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
    $rssfeed .= '<copyright>Copyright (C) 2016 http://localhost:8080/rsst/CloudRobotics/rsst/public/index</copyright>';

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY pID";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die ("Could not execute query");

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
        extract($row);

        $rssfeed .= '<item>';
        $rssfeed .= '<title>' . $pID . '</title>';
        $rssfeed .= '<description>' . $pName . '</description>';
        $rssfeed .= '</item>';
    }

    $rssfeed .= '</channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '</rss>';

    echo $rssfeed;
?>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t086.png)

Comment: please provide errors you getting

Comment: The error I am getting is a Feed code error - Internet Explorer cannot display this feed.  I will even post a screenshot